# Binding Canvas size (width, height) to viewmodel properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have canvas on my grid, with some defaults size.
I load file using command in my viewmodel.
Now i want to change size of canvas dynamically to value i read from file. 
What is the best way to implement this ? bind widht and height to properties which implements ipropertychanged? or dependency property ?

Comment: INPC CLR properties should do it for you. No need for DP's.

Comment: @RohitVats so just bind width and height to properties and implement inpc ?

Comment: Yeah that should do it for you.